# Using Beautfiul Soup to extract specific groups of links from a blogspot website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, automation

I want to extract, let's say, every 7th year link on a school website. On the archives, it's pretty easy to find with ctrl + f "year-7". It's not that easy on beautifulSoup, though. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = '~school URL~'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

This gives me every link on the website archive. Every link that matters to me is pretty much like this:

```
~school URL~blogspot.com/2020/10/mathematics-activity-year-x.html
```

I tried storing the "(link.get('href'))" on a variable and searching for "year-x" on it but that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I'd search through it? Blogspot search is horrific. I'm doing this as a project to help kids from a poor area on finding their classes easier, because it was all just left on the website for the next school year and there's hundreds of link without tags for different school years. I'm trying to at least compile a list of the links for each school year to help them.

Comment: So if I understand, you want to get all links where `year-7`?

Comment: Yes! And then do it for year-8, year-9...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the other HTML links (what you do and don’t want)?

Comment: it'd be something like:
```
~school URL~blogspot.com/2020/10/geography-activity-year-1.html
~school URL~blogspot.com/2020/10/history-activity-year-3.html
~school URL~blogspot.com/2020/10/english-activity-year-8.html
```
And so on. It's all mashed in together.

Comment: What's the actual HTML markup?

Comment: What do you mean? This is the result I get after "link.get('href'))" gets me every link on the page. Now I'd like to search through these links to find "year-x" and store them somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I understand, you want to extract the years from from the links.* Try using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) to extract the years.

In your case it would be:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """<a href="blogspot.com/2020/10/mathematics-activity-year-x.html"</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

years = []

for tag in soup.find_all("a"):
    link = tag.get("href")
    year = re.search(r"year-.?", link).group()
    years.append(year)

print(years)
```

Output:

```
['year-x']
```

**Edit** Try using a CSS selector to select all `href`’s that end with `year-7.html`

```
...
for tag in soup.select('a[href$="year-7.html"]'):
        print(tag)
```

Comment: Sorry if I did not make myself very clear, I'll try rewording:

After I print every URL of the website's archive, I have every year's activity, like this:

~URL~.blogspot.com/2020/10/math-activity-year-2.html
~URL~.blogspot.com/2020/10/math-activity-year-9.html
~URL~.blogspot.com/2020/10/math-activity-year-5.html

Multiply that by hundreds...Lots of links. So I want to search for every URL that contains 'year-7' so I can gather all year 7 links somewhere. How do I that?

Comment: I managed to finish the project using pandas, but thanks for trying it with me!